# Parseuser save in background still saving to it's local storage when exception is thrown

Tags: java, android, email, parse-platform

I wanted to allow the user to update their email and it works just fine when they enter everything correctly but when they don't something weird happens

So for this example (which is the one that I have been testing) the current user email is `email@gmail.com` and they want to replace it with `h` as their email.

Here's the code for updating user email

```
// get current user
currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

// get user input (shortened to show result)
final String email = "h";

// reset user email
currentUser.setUsername(email);
currentUser.setEmail(email);

// save progress
currentUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback()
{
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e)
    {
        if (null == e)
        {
            // success
            // tell user of success
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "new email is " + email,
                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // restart activity to update information
            restartActivity();
        }
        else
        {   
            // update failed
            // look at the ParseException to see what happened.
            errorMessageDialog("Oops!", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

So obviously there will be a parse exception thrown and it will be that it is not a valid email address and when I check the database that is the case. Nothing was updated in any of the rows; however, if I check the current email later on then something unexpected happens

```
// get current user
currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

// get username
currentUser.getUsername();

// get email
currentUser.getEmail();
```

When I run that code, it says my email and username are `h` but if I check the database it's still `example@gmail.com`

It appears that parse still updates it's local cache even when there was an exception thrown from the database? I don't know what the problem is perhaps `saveInBackground(new SaveCallback()` is the wrong method to use?